# How to send email to all members when a post is updated by user?

Tags: organic-groups

I am creating  a rules to send an email when a (node with content type update) is updated 
which has field_og_audience as field and it is placed on the groups page using advanced form block.

I want to send an email when node (with content type update) is updated by user then all 
the members of the group(selected in the field_og_audience) should recieve an email.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom action? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7 - This can be fired by rules and accept the OG ID, which you could use in turn to load the users and send off an e-mail. I'm not aware of a point-n-click solution.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein I added a rule for content as shown below to send mail to all members

Answer (score 1):

EVENT

**After saving new content**

CONDITIONS

Entity is group content

**Parameter: Entity: [node]**

ACTIONS

Get group members from group audience
Parameter: Group content: [node]
Provides variables: Fetch a List of group members (group_members)

**Loop**
**Parameter: List: [group-members]**
**List item: Get list of group members and their email ids (list_grp_members_emails)**

**Send mail Parameter: To: [list-grp-members-emails:mail], Subject: Notification: Content..., Message: Test**